# compare java element from a findAll()

Tags: java, spring, list, repository, crud

I have to remove duplicates from an object list retrieved from a CrudRepository.

I done that :

```
if (!prospectionRepository.findAll().isEmpty()) {
    List<Prospection> all = prospectionRepository.findAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < all.size()-1; i++) {
        for (int k = i+1;k < all.size(); k++) {
            if (all.get(i).getProspectNumber() == all.get(k).getProspectNumber()) {
                all.remove(all.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    prospectionRepository.save(all);
}
```

However, duplicates are not removed from the list and they are then persisted when I do not want to.

Comment: What Java type is returned by getProspectNumber()?  If it's not a  primative your "==" comparison is not going to work.  If it returns a Java Object, use .equals(...) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem edit

After conversation in chat, additional parameters have to be taken into account:

> 1. multiples `Prospect` may have the same `prospect number` but they do have an unique primary key in the database. Consequently, the duplicate filter cannot rely on the `Prospect` equality
> 2. a `Prospect` has a *visited status* which defined whether the `Prospect` has been contacted by the company or not. The two main status are `NEW` and `MET`. Only one `Prospect` can be `MET`. Other duplicates (with the same `prospect number`) can only be `NEW`

## Algorithm

The problem needs to an additional step to be solved:

1. The prospects need to be grouped by `prospect number`. At this stage, we will a `<ProspectNumber, List<Prospect>>` mapping. However, the `List<Prospect>` must end up with a single element according to the rules defined earlier
2. Within a list, then if the prospect has not be met **AND** another prospect is found with a *met* status, then the first prospect is to be discarded

Consequently, the list will be generated with the following rules:

- If a prospect has no duplicate in terms of prospect numbers, it is kept regardless its status
- If a prospect has duplicate in terms of prospect number, only the `met` one is kept
- If multiple prospects have the same prospect number but no one is `met`, then an arbitrary one is met: `Stream` does not guarantee to loop in the list order.

## Code

The trick is to go through a `Map` as the key will hold the unicity. If your propect number is a specific type, this will assume that `equals()` and `hashCode()` are properly defined.

**disclaimer: code is untested**

```java
List<Prospection> all = prospectionRepository.findAll().stream()
        // we instantiate here a Map<ProspectNumber, Prospect>
        // There is no need to have a Map<ProspectNumber, List<Propect>> 
        // as the merge function will do the sorting for us
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // Key: use the prospect number
                prospect -> prospect.getProspectNumber(),
                // Value: use the propect object itself
                prospect -> prospect,
                // Merge function: two prospects with the same prospect number
                // are found: keep the one with the MET status or the first one
                (oldProspect, newProspect) -> {
                    if(oldProspect.getStatus() == MET){
                        return oldProspect;
                    } else if (newProspect.getStatus() == MET){
                        return newProspect;
                    } else{
                        // return the first one, arbitrary decision
                        return oldProspect;
                    }
                }
        ))
        // get map values only
        .values()
        // stream it in order to collect its as a List
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
prospectionRepository.save(all);
```

`Map.values()` actually return a `Collection`. So if your `prospectionRepository.save(...)` can accept a `Collection` (not only `List`), you can go faster. I also use the following synonym:

- **[static method reference](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx)**: `Prospect::getProspectNumber` is the `Function` equivalent to `prospect -> prospect.getProspectNumber()`
- **[`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--)**: is equivalent to `prospect -> prospect`
- **Ternary operator**: it returns the same thing but written differently

```java
Collection<Prospection> all = prospectionRepository.findAll().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Prospect::getProspectNumber,
                Function.identity(),
                (oldProspect, newProspect) -> newProspect.getStatus() == MET ? newProspect : oldProspect
        )).values();
prospectionRepository.save(all);
```

---

<sub>For your information, if two `Prospection` having the same `ProspectNumber` are equals, then a simple [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) would have been enough:</sub>

```
List<Prospection> all = prospectionRepository.findAll()
        .stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
prospectionRepository.save(all);
```

Comment: The problem is that will note delete duplicates because whatever happens, the Id's will be unique and different. I have to compare field of my object

Comment: I understand, I'll edit my answer but first I have a question: if you find two `Prospection` with the same `ProspectNumber`, how do you know which one you'll remove?

Comment: A status (Enumeration) that notifies whether the prospect has been modified : if I have prospection1 and prospection2 with same prospectNumber but prospection2 has a status "MEET" involve that I will delete prospection1

Comment: And what is two prospection have been modified? How can you make the difference? E.g: `Prospect1 (number 1), Prospect2 (number 2), Prospect3 (number 1)`. How do you know if you discard *Prospect1* or *Prospect3*? If you have a status, what if they have the same status?

Comment: It is impossible because after insertion, the duplicates have by default a status "NEW"

Comment: So in my example, which one do you discard? and why? (assumed they are ordered)

Comment: Basically I run a Spring batch job that will persist the lines of a csv in database. This is done from a website, which allows to upload the csv with the prospects, however if the csv contains duplicates I want to delete them after insertion. So let's imagine that I have in base: prospect1 (number: "+3376221251", Status: NEW) and prospect2 (number: "+3376221251", Status: MEET). Here the prospect2 was used by a commercial and I want to keep it and not the prospect1 which just a duplicate of a new csv upload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156597/discussion-between-al1-and-fosfor).

Comment: I'm here to continue

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
List<Prospection> all = prospectionRepository.findAll();
Set<Object> prospectNumbers = new HashSet<Object>();
Iterator<Prospection> it = all.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Prospection item = iterator.next();
    Object itemNumer = item.getProspectNumber();
    if (prospectNumbers.contains(itemNumber)) {
        it.remove();
    } else {
        prospectNumbers.add(itemNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hrm...  `prospectionRepository.remove(item);` could potentially delete data when the user just wants to remove the duplicates from the resultSet.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a HashSet with the prospectNumber as value. The HashSet cannot contains duplicate keys. After that you can iterate over your List and removing all your duplicate elements. Hope this will help you!

Comment: HashSet doesn't have keys. Did you mean HashMap?

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry! I've made a confusion. Yea, HashSet doesn't have keys, but he can use a HashSet for getting all the no-duplicate keys and after that, use that HashSet for iterating over the List and remove the duplicates. Thx!

Comment: @DinaBogdan actually, if the only constraint is *I need a list for my `save()` method*, he can just create a `list` and use `list.addAll(theHashSet);`. In this way, there is no need to do any loop